# How do I include an ASP.NET file in a Magento PHP page?

Tags: php, asp.net, magento, server-side-includes

Here is the situation: 
I have an ASP.NET main site, with a Magento buy-online section. 
The .NET site contains the header with menus generated dynamically, and I have to reuse the same header in the Magento side of the site.

I can't just copy the HTML in a static block, since the menu items are generated dynamically 
from a Database. 
I tried using an Iframe, but I'm using superfish for the menus, so when the sub-menus show up they don't fit in the iframe, so we don't see the whole menu. 
So I tried using the php  include, with both the following syntaxes: 
include("/GetHeader.aspx?l=en");
and
include("http://siteurl/GetHeader.aspx?l=en");
but both fail to show anything, the page is just blank.

My php.ini is set to show errors and warnings and both
allow_url_fopen and allow_url_include are set to On

Any idea on how to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I really don't think this is cleanly possible with a plain server stack.  There might be something you could do if you have [Varnish](http://www.varnish-cache.org/) running using [Edge Side Includes](http://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/2.1/tutorial/esi.html).

The PHP `include` function is meant for including files during compile time through the file system.  This means it doesn't perform any HTTP request and therefore does not run through the ASP.NET engine.  That's why it doesn't work in the way you are using it.

Answer (score 0):

You could call the page directly using a [web request like feature](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2007/06/php_tip_how_get_web_page_using_curl) of PHP.

Comment: Agreed, I wouldn't use the method myself, but I answered the question as asked. I can't understand why he wants to do what he is doing and I hoped the mess of the method that would work would steer him toward the best solution (writing a widget in PHP that interacted with the database directly).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `allow_url_fopen` I believe you can do this:

```
print file_get_contents('http://siteurl/GetHeader.aspx?l=en');
```